# Tachnun in Nissan

Tags: minhag, tachanun, nissan

Why is there no Tachnun said in the month of Nissan?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47636

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MB: 429(2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=4) Twelve Nesiyim brought korbonos for twelve days and for each it was Yom Tov on their day, Erev Pesach, Pesach and Isru Chag added together gives a majority of the month in at least partial Kedushah, therefore the whole month is considered Kodesh.

The gemara in Menochos 65a says the the first eight days were designated as a celebration for the re-establishemnet of the Tomid at the time of the Sadduccees and no fasting was permitted on these days. (Be'er Haitaiv)

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of Kedushah, so much as it is one of communal Simchah and festivities.

Comment: Please look at the MB. States clearly since the majority of the month is is in 'Kedushah' therefore we make the whole month Kodesh, not Yom Tov.

Comment: That's very interesting. What is the defining difference between Kedushah and Simchah in terms of saying Tachanun?  We certainly recite it in Eretz Yisrael and in Yerushalayim, where there is a higher level of Kedushah, and we do not recite it when there is a groom present, so is there something about a day - or month - of Kedushah that gives it some level of Simchah that eliminates the need for reciting Tachanun, or does a certain level of Simchah create an atmosphere of Kedushah (or vice versa)?  Or does there need to be some level of Kedushah in a Simchah-dik atmosphere together?

Comment: its because of rov, most of the month we don't say it, and iesh omrim that is because of the festivities of the third temple, they will take place on the final days of nisan