# Why not say tachanun until 2 Cheshvan?

Tags: minhag, calendar, tachanun, tishrei

It's recorded in most siddurim I've used that some people have the custom to skip tachanun on *Isru Chag* (the day after Sukkos), and start again the day after, while others don't resume saying it until the second day of *Cheshvan*.
*Needless to say, those shuls are favored by many during this time.* ;-)

**What is special about this time period, in between Sukkos and the beginning of Cheshvan, that suggests skipping tachanun?**

Comment: Related question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47636/5323

Answer (score 3):

From what i understand, it is for the same reason that there's no tachanun during Nisan. (See [Tachnun in Nissan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/tachnun-in-nissan))

There, once we aren't saying tachanun during most of the month (first because of the Nesiyim, then Pesach), we don't say for the rest. Here to, once we have skipped tachanun for most of the month, we don't say it for the rest of the month. First there's Rosh Hashanah (2 days), Yom Kippur (2 days), between YK and Sukkot (4 days), and Sukkot (9-10 days). That totals more than half, so there's no tachanun.

Comment: +1. That was going to be my next question ("why is Tishrei different from Nissan?")

Comment: Before I learned of this minhag, I davened in a minyan which said tachanun on these days and I asked why Tishrei is different. I was told by a rav that the nature of Tishrei is in line with what tachanun stands for while the general theme of Nissan is different from the message of tachanun. So while we might not say tachanun on certain days in Tishrei, we say tachanunim frequently so saying it on days when we have no other reason not to say it makes sense.

Comment: YK is basically an all day Tachanun...

Comment: @Danno I had previously heard something similar. [Let's find out](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47636/5323).

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know about others, but Chabad only says Tachanun where it says so in the Machzor. It won't say it By Krias Shma SheAl Hamitta, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to answer both your question and what's in the recent comments:

It was estimated that it took 5-7 days for travelers who made the pilgrimage (aliyah laregel) from the furthest places to return home. Thus, the week after the end of Succot is considered a semi holiday.

Why is Tishrei different than Nissan when there is no Tachanun the whole month? I surmise that Tachanun is said during Aseret Y'mei Teshuva already. Since this is a period when you are confessing your sins and are asking for G-d's mercy and forgiveness, it is a time you'd WANT to say Tachanun. So, no matter how you view things, you're saying Tachnaun during some part of the month, anyway. Perhaps, that's what went into the thinking of those that restart Tachanun on Tishrei 24 (Tishrei 25 in years such as this year.)

Of course, based on what I mentioned the question should be "reversed" - Why is Nissan different than Tishrei? I understand cancelling Tachanun after Pesach, but why before it?

Comment: Before Pesach is considered a semi-holiday because that's when the Nesiyim brought their gifts when the mishkan was inaugurated (as mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Who estimates that it took 5-7 days? The Talmud estimates that it took 14 days. That's why they delayed asking for rain until 7 Marcheshvan.