# Why the difference between Tishrei and Nissan for tachanun?

Tags: tachanun, months, nissan, tishrei

As mentioned [elsewhere on this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6602/5323), we don't say tachanun during the entire month of Nissan, because a majority of the month is spent "in *kedusha*," skipping tachanun -- therefore we omit tachanun for the entire month.

Don't we do the same during Tishrei? Based on the above reasoning, why should we say tachanun at all during the month of Tishrei? (*assuming that we don't say tachanun after Sukkos*)

Comment: Related question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47612/5323

Comment: Well, you're assuming that we don't say tachanun after Sukkos...

Comment: @Matt [Correct](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/47636/revisions) ;)

Comment: @Matt No he isn't. 1,2,9 Tishrei and 11 Tishrei to 23 Tishrei and 30 Tishrei is 17 days.

Comment: @DoubleAA But also I'm not sure about Rosh Hashana, considering that we say Avinu Malkeinu...

Comment: Are you asking why we don't skip Tachanun during Aseret Yemei Teshuva, or why some do say Tachanun after Sukkot?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm asking why anyone would say tachanun, at any point of the month that is not already covered by Yom Tov or other excuse, given Nissan's רובו ככולו.

Answer (score 7):

Nissan starts without Tachnun because it is the time when the Mishkan was inaugurated - that is the first 12 days. Then the 13th is the Isru Chag of those 12 days ([The Tzemach Tzedek quoting the Maharil](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1609&pgnum=182)), and then there is no Tachnun on the 14th because the Korban Pesach was brought, and then Pesach. So there is no opportunity to say Tachanun until the majority of the month is already without Tachnun. (See Shulchan Aruch HaRav O.C. [429:9](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/429/9.htm)).

In Tishrei, that situation only exists when the end of Succos is reached, so it would seem that the rule that once you don't say Tachnun for the majority of the month you don't say it for the rest of the month only applies once the majority of the month has actually passed without Tachnun.

Answer (score 1):

The Rav of our shul spoke about this when discussing our shul minhag of not saying tachanun until Rosh Chodesh Cheshvan. Note that this is our shul minhag as other shuls in the community start tachanun after Isru Chag (or maybe on Isru Chag, I am not sure).

The first part of the month continues tachanun because of the inyan of teshuvah and din. After Succos, we continue not saying tachanun because of the inyan of simcha and adding to Shmini Atzeres because it is a "Regel bifnei Atzmo" rather than the end of the chag (like the last day of Pesach). We also do not say tachanun for the week after Shavuos since there was a week afterwards that the korbon chagigah could be brought.  Even though a separate chagigah was not brought on Shmini Atzeres (and the Ymei miluim of Succos are over) we still extend the simcha of the Chag.

This is from memory as to the explanation that our Rav gave for our shul minhag (which goes back to the founding of our shul as a separate minyon.  Note that other shuls do not have this minhag (as I said earlier).

I do not recall the sources that our rav brought. Since there are those that do say tachanun, there is what to rely on in both ways.

Comment: I have never heard of an "inyan" of adding to shmini atzeret. Has anyone else? What other application does this "inyan" have?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the intention is *Isru Chag*, which is exactly that – extending the *Regel* stay in Jerusalem ("tying to the corners of the altar"). Then it makes sense: *Sh"A* is **not** a fancy *Isru Chag* for *Sukkos*, but rather a *Regel bifnei atzmo*, thus requiring a day of *Isru Chag*. The only problem is the mention of *Acharon shel Pesach*, which surely is real *Yom Tov*, and not an *Isru Chag*. Maybe, there, he just means to explain the uniqueness of *Sh"A*, independently from the *inyan* of *Isru Chag*?