# Tachanun In Sivan

Tags: minhag, tachanun

According to an emailed halacha I received,

> Some have the custom to not say Tachnun until the 12th of Sivan, and in the Diaspora until the 13th of Sivan. Shulchan Aruch w/Mishnah Brurah 494:3, Piskei Tshuvos 494:9

If one does not say Tachanun until the 13th, and the month, as is the case when the first of Sivan is on a Sunday, has 3 other Shabbatot and the first day of Rosh Chodesh Tammuz, then there are 16 days on which this person does not say Tachanun.

Following the premise as discussed in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6602/1362) and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47613/1362) answer, that once one does not say Tachanun for over half the month, one does not say it for the rest of the month, would it be proper not to say Tachanun for the remainder of Sivan?

Comment: Based on your question, the simplest answer is we may need to reject one of the assumptions (either no tachanun for a week after Shavuot or no Tachanun because half a month lacks it). Indeed neither appears to have been widely practiced historically.

Comment: I would think that the premise would be based on consistency and not what happens only in certain years. Also note that on Shabbat, *Tzitkatcha Tzedek* is recited (on the Shabbatot after Shavuot or the 13th). This is considered a "substitute" for Tachanun, or more correctly, it is omitted on days when Tachanun is not said. So, if the place is saying *Tzidkatcha* that knocks out your premise.

Comment: @DanF how is tzidkatcha a substitute for tachanun? It is not a petition, is not said at Shacharit, is said standing, ...

Comment: @DoubleAA Are there any communities who disagree with the premise that צדקתך is only said on dates which would get תחנון had those dates fallen out during the week? It’s an explicit Shulchan Aruch (OC 292:2).

Comment: @Doniel depends how you count RH https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%97_%D7%90 and Yom Kippur https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%92